# Pytorch on CPU without AVX Support

Tags: python, windows, pytorch, avx

I'm currently working on a Python project that uses torch, torchvision, and torchaudio packages. On my local machine, everything is working fine but after I have deployed the project on a Windows server that has Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6240R CPU, the project crashes in file 'fbgemm.dll' with code 0xc000001d.

After some research, I found that it may happen because the CPU of the server doesn't support AVX and AVX2. I want to make sure that I'm searching in the right direction, and if that is so, is there a way to install the packages without AVX support? I've installed them using pip before.

Thank you in advance.